# How to capture invisible content of Tab and Recyclerview in Android?

Tags: android, image

I have a layout which contain TabLayout and ViewPager, I have 3 tab.layout code is look like

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nest_scrollview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/tab_background"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

now I would like to take screen shot, it should take all tab and it's contain.

I used below code for take screen shot, but it's only take visible part on screen.

```
public Bitmap takeScreenshot() {
        View rootView = findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView();
        rootView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        return rootView.getDrawingCache();
    }

    public void saveBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        imagePath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/screenshot.png");
        FileOutputStream fos;
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imagePath);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.flush();
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("GREC", e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can capture entire recyclerview using below code.

```
public class Utils {
    public Utils() {
    }

    public Bitmap getScreenshotFromRecyclerView(RecyclerView view) {
        Bitmap bigBitmap = null;

        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = view.getAdapter();

        if (adapter != null) {
            int size = adapter.getItemCount();
            int height = 0;
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            int iHeight = 0;
            final int maxMemory = (int) (Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 1024);

            // Use 1/8th of the available memory for this memory cache.
            final int cacheSize = maxMemory / 8;
            LruCache<String, Bitmap> bitmaCache = new LruCache<>(cacheSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = adapter.createViewHolder(view, adapter.getItemViewType(i));
                adapter.onBindViewHolder(holder, i);
                holder.itemView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                holder.itemView.layout(0, 0, holder.itemView.getMeasuredWidth(), holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight());
                holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                holder.itemView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap drawingCache = holder.itemView.getDrawingCache();
                if (drawingCache != null) {
                    bitmaCache.put(String.valueOf(i), drawingCache);
                }
//                holder.itemView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
//                holder.itemView.destroyDrawingCache();
                height += holder.itemView.getMeasuredHeight();
            }

            bigBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getMeasuredWidth(), height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas bigCanvas = new Canvas(bigBitmap);
            bigCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                Bitmap bitmap = bitmaCache.get(String.valueOf(i));
                bigCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0f, iHeight, paint);
                iHeight += bitmap.getHeight();
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
        }
        storeImage(bigBitmap, "myRecipeTest.jpg");
        return bigBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the bitmap into image and save it into the sdcard.
     *
     * @param imageData -Bitmap image.
     * @param filename  -Name of the image.
     * @return
     */
    public boolean storeImage(Bitmap imageData, String filename) {
        // get path to external storage (SD card)
        File sdIconStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath() + "/myAppDir/");
        // create storage directories, if they don't exist
        sdIconStorageDir.mkdirs();
        try {
            String filePath = sdIconStorageDir.toString() + File.separator + filename;
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
            BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
            Log.e("<== SHARE ==>", "storeImage: Image Saved at----" + filePath);
            // choose another format if PNG doesn't suit you
            imageData.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bos);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w("TAG", "Error saving image file: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```